# Find and Replace number text to fraction text

Tags: vba, replace, format, find

I have two tables.

Droplist Table have 2 columns:

- [HeaderA] contains the lookup values
- [HeaderA_D] contains the replace values

| HeaderA | HeaderA_D |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/50 |
| 2 | 1/100 |
| 3 | 1/200 |
| 4 | 1/500 |

Table1 Table

- [HeaderB] is the column I am trying with find matching values from Droplist[HeaderA] and replace with Droplist[HeaderA_D]

| HeaderB |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

Current Results

| HeaderB |
| --- |
| 18624 |
| 1/100 |
| 1/200 |
| 1/500 |

Expected Results

| HeaderB |
| --- |
| 1/50 |
| 1/100 |
| 1/200 |
| 1/500 |

Problem:

I am having trouble to find '1' and replace it with '1/50'. It keeps replacing it with 18624 which is 1/1/1950 in number format "Date"

I tried:

My code is below and I made sure both is in .Numberformat = "Text"

'''

```
Sub Find_Replace()

Dim b, c As Variant

Dim j As Integer

Set b = Range("Droplist[HeaderA]")

Set c = Range("Droplist[HeaderA_D]")

    For j = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("Droplist[HeaderA]"), "<>")
    
        Range("Table1[HeaderB]").Select
        Range("Table1[HeaderB]").NumberFormat = "@"
        
        Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "@"
        Selection.Replace What:=b(j), Replacement:=c(j), LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=True
        
    Next j

End Sub
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reperformed your issue on VBA again, when I change the raw data as text 1/50 and continuous to execute VBA code, the same issue happen on my excel again. I think this problem is cause by the `find and replace` function in excel, in order to solve it, it will be better to use `replace` function, here is the solution, accept if help :)

My raw data

[image]

The VBA code with replace function:

```
Sub Find_Replace()

Dim b, c As Variant
Dim replaceValue As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long, headerLastrow As Long, replaceTime As Long

headerLastrow = Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lastrow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Set b = Sheet1.Range("A1", "A" & lastrow)
Set c = Sheet1.Range("B1", "B" & lastrow)

Sheet1.Range("E2", "E" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "@"

    For j = 1 To lastrow
            
        For replaceTime = 1 To headerLastrow
        replaceValue = c(replaceTime).Text
        Sheet1.Cells(j, 5).Value = Replace(Sheet1.Cells(j, 5).Value, b(replaceTime), replaceValue)
        Next
    Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Kin Siang but that's not the problem.
My problem is running the code and Table1[HeaderB] doesn't return the correct value when i try to find "1" and replace with "1/50"

Comment: ya, i know that problem is on the text 1/50, it can solve by change the format first then update value, let me show you the solution later.

Comment: You may check my edited answer ,it solve the problem now :)

Comment: I guess my table is a little misleading. Table1[HeaderB] have many rows. I just use 1,2,3,4 as demonstration. It could be 1,1,3,4,1,2,3,4,4.
I do not know which row will contain the value "1"

Comment: Yes, it can be achieve by perform looping in the replace function ,see my edited answer and accept if help :)